# Screen tracking data on Firebase Analytics

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

According to the Firebase documentation I don't need to add anything to record the screen viewing data from my users. Here is a snippet straight out of the docs:

> **setScreenName:screenClass:**
>
> Sets the current screen name, which specifies the current visual
>   context in your app. This helps identify the areas in your app where
>   users spend their time and how they interact with your app.
>
> Note that screen reporting is enabled automatically and records the
>   class name of the current UIViewController for you without requiring
>   you to call this method. If you implement viewDidAppear in your
>   UIViewController but do not call [super viewDidAppear:], that screen
>   class will not be automatically tracked. The class name can optionally
>   be overridden by calling this method in the viewDidAppear callback of
>   your UIViewController and specifying the screenClassOverride
>   parameter. If your app does not use a distinct UIViewController for
>   each screen, you should call this method and specify a distinct
>   screenName each time a new screen is presented to the user.
>
> The screen name and screen class remain in effect until the current
>   UIViewController changes or a new call to setScreenName:screenClass:
>   is made.

Its been over 24hrs and I can't see any data on the Firebase console. The first question is, where should this data be?

Second, am I doing this wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "data"? Did you mean the screen parameters? They currently do not show up in the report yet (I couldn't find them anywhere in my own console). The parameters are not currently displayed in the report but they will be useful in later features.

Comment: Firebase looks great on paper, but stuff like this is extremely frustrating.

Comment: What is the current status of this issue? Screen tracking are shown in the firebase dashboard??

Answer (score 1):

The screen parameters will accompany the events reported to the server but they currently are not displayed on Developer Console yet (at least in my developer console). In the Firebase Summit 2016 in Berlin, Firebase team gave some sneakpeeks of the new features and you can see the screen parameters reported in real-time and also in Crash Report to know which sequence of events and screens that lead to the crash (Summit [video](https://youtu.be/TxAOjwSc9sY?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmYSsW6ED2QvHxuI3UzT0WZ))